# Creating new environment to wrap a table

Tags: tables, environments

I have many tables (and figures) which are exceeding the margins of my document and I don't want to change each one separately. I'm trying to create a new environment around `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` that resizes everything and I just switch the name of the environment by lookup.

Here are my three examples.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % enable graphics, images and resizebox


\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{my_table} {
\begin{table}[!h]

\makebox[1 \width][c]{       %centering table
\resizebox{0.87 \width}{!}{   %resize table

\BODY

}
}

\end{table}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Table 1}
\begin{table}[!h]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline
  & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 \\ 
  \hline
Only 1 track & -0.53 (-0.65/-0.41) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.21 (-0.35/-0.07) \\ 
  Age selection $>$= 15 &  & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.57 (-0.71/-0.43) \\ 
  \% of curric tracked &  &  & 0 (-0.23/0.23) & 0.59 (0.31/0.88) \\ 
  Vocational Index &  &  &  & -0.27 (-0.36/-0.19) \\ 
  Intercept & 1.77 (1.7/1.84) & 1.94 (1.85/2.03) & 1.94 (1.69/2.18) & 1.54 (1.27/1.81) \\ 
   \hline R square: & 23\% & 32\% & 32\% & 40\% \\ Sample size: & 195 & 195 & 195 & 183 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}


\section{Table 2}

\begin{table}[!h]

\makebox[1 \width][c]{       %centering table
\resizebox{0.87 \width}{!}{   %resize table

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline
  & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 \\ 
  \hline
Only 1 track & -0.53 (-0.65/-0.41) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.21 (-0.35/-0.07) \\ 
  Age selection $>$= 15 &  & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.57 (-0.71/-0.43) \\ 
  \% of curric tracked &  &  & 0 (-0.23/0.23) & 0.59 (0.31/0.88) \\ 
  Vocational Index &  &  &  & -0.27 (-0.36/-0.19) \\ 
  Intercept & 1.77 (1.7/1.84) & 1.94 (1.85/2.03) & 1.94 (1.69/2.18) & 1.54 (1.27/1.81) \\ 
   \hline R square: & 23\% & 32\% & 32\% & 40\% \\ Sample size: & 195 & 195 & 195 & 183 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}

} %close resize
} %close centering


\caption{Table 2}
\end{table}

\section{Table 3}

\begin{my_table}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline
  & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 \\ 
  \hline
Only 1 track & -0.53 (-0.65/-0.41) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.31 (-0.44/-0.18) & -0.21 (-0.35/-0.07) \\ 
  Age selection $>$= 15 &  & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.38 (-0.51/-0.26) & -0.57 (-0.71/-0.43) \\ 
  \% of curric tracked &  &  & 0 (-0.23/0.23) & 0.59 (0.31/0.88) \\ 
  Vocational Index &  &  &  & -0.27 (-0.36/-0.19) \\ 
  Intercept & 1.77 (1.7/1.84) & 1.94 (1.85/2.03) & 1.94 (1.69/2.18) & 1.54 (1.27/1.81) \\ 
   \hline R square: & 23\% & 32\% & 32\% & 40\% \\ Sample size: & 195 & 195 & 195 & 183 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Table 3}
\end{my_table}


\end{document}
```

To simplify:

1) First table exceeds margins

2) Second table is the same table but with `\makebox` and `\resizebox` to resize the table to fit. It works as I expected.

3) Third table is the problem. I take the `\makebox ..\resizebox` strategy create a environment with the package `environ` and `\NewEnviron` and then use this environment to wrap table 3. I get several errors which you can reproduce by just copying this MWE.

Any ideas on how to make the wrapper around the environment work?

Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: One step in the right direction would be to remove the underscore from the environments name. That will not work as expected. Secondly remove that makebox. For centering use `\centering` within `table`.

Comment: Do not resize tables, simply use a smaller standard font (`\small, \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \tiny`) before of tabular, but if you need reduce to a ridiculous font size to fit the margins as in your example (that need the `\tiny` size!),  then is much better redesign  the table or left  landscape pages for this type of tables.

Comment: `\makebox[1 \width][c]{       %centering table` does not do anything at all, it makes a box the width of the content and then "centres" the content in that box, but as the box is the same size this does nothing at all.